# How to declare this.someProperty in react with typeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I'm getting  `TS2339: Property 'someProperty ' does not exist on type ''.` I'm trying to add new property to my react component which is `this.someProperty`

```
    interfaceMyComponentState {
        allClear: boolean;
        data: Array<object>;
    }

    interface MyComponentProps {}

    class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {

        constructor(props) {

            super(props);
            this.state = {
                allClear: false,
                data: []
            };
            this.someProperty = []; // this is not a prop nor a state
        }


    }
```

How can i declare `this.someProperty` so that i don't get typecript error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define it as a class property first.

```
class MyComponent extends ... {
  // string[] so that TypeScript doesn't automatically infer never[] or any[].
  // change string[] to whatever your actual type for someProperty is.
  private someProperty: string[] = [];
  public state = { allClear: false, data: [] };

  // no need for the constructor if all you do is set properties/state
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using any.

**someProperty:any**

Comment: any should be a last resort, not first.

Comment: Yes. Thanks Madara!